# How to view/download file under a custom subdir in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After uploading a file, we would like to make the file available for view and download. The file could be in common format such as `pdf`, `jp`g or `xls`. After a user clicks the file name, the file is downloaded and opened by local app on user's PC. Here is what we did:

```
<%= link_to r.file_name, r.storage_subdir + '/' + r.file_name %>
```

`r.storage_subdir` returns `storage/multi_item_orderx_order/15`. `storage` is a subdir under `root`. `r.file_name` returns `IMG_3002.jpg`

When clicking the file name, there pops up an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/upload/storage/multi_item_orderx_order/15/IMG_3002.jpg"
```

(Not sure how `upload` was put in front of `storage`). Used `save link as` to download and the file is only a partial in size and there shows nothing after clicking it. What is the right way to both view and download a file? Or at least to download a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't understand how to render uploaded file then you uploading it wrong. Here is a small tutorial for you.

### How to implement file upload function in your rails application

First of all add this gems to your `Gemfile` and then execute `bundle install` in console.

```
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
```

Let's imagine that you have model `User` and you need to give users ability to upload profile picture. When `bundler install` successfuly installed new gems we need to create `Uploader` via generator.

```
rails g uploader avatar
```

And let's configure it:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{mode.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_limit: [64, 64]
  end
end
```

Few words about this configuration: we said carrierwave to use RMagick gem, said which storage we would like to use and where data must be stored and implemented resize for thumbnails.

Now need to add column `avatar` to users table. Let's create migration:

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_users avatar:string
```

And now lets mount our uploader in `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

That's all! Carrierwave configured and ready to use in your application! Now you can create view like:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This form will give you ability to upload avatar. In controller you need to pass params[:user][:avatar] to model to create\update user's avatar.

And if you need to render image to view you can use something like this:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:thumb) %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.thumb.url %>
```

Don't forget to install `imagemagick` headers via system's package manager (`apt-get` \ `yum` \ `pacman` \ `brew` \ etc) because if you will not do it, bundler will fall.

If you got any questions, check out [carrierwave github page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [carrierwave documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/frames).

Comment: `axvm`, thank you for the answer. But my post is about how to view/download uploaded file which has been uploaded and NOT about how to upload file. Also the file is not necessary an image file (could be pdf, jpg and xlx) so we can not just use image_tag for it.

Comment: you can use carrierwave to upload any kind of files, not just images. I provided links in the end of answer to github and documentation, check it out.

Comment: You wrote 'how to view/download uploaded file which has been uploaded'
You didn't provide info how you uploading files so noone can answer you how you can download something that uploaded with unknown method. Please, fix your question.

Comment: I use simple_form to upload a file and File object to process it (no use of upload gems) . I dont' quite understand why you need to know how the file is uploaded and file is a file. You can assume that the file is already somewhere under root and how to present it to users for view/download.

Comment: You need to move file to rails `public` directory to make it accessible for downloading. If you are reinventing wheel check out how it works in gems like `carrierwave` or `papperclip`.

Comment: The file is uploaded and saved in storage instead of public. Both `storage` and `public` have the full right by the web.

Comment: Then move it to `public` folder then or configure `nginxs` to serve `storage` folder too. You gave too small information to understand your problem and to help you. I am pretty sure if you can't describe the situation then you doing it wrong.